# Django - Why are migration commands not working?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am creating a simple django project by following the django documentation. I created an app polls and added models and urls and also added the app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

But when I try to run a migrate command nothing works. I don't get any result/output on console. I tried to stop the command using Ctrl+X but even that doesn't work. I've tried `python manage.py makemigrations` `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py showmigrations` but nothing is working.

Comment: Ctrl+X? Do you get any output from the commands you are running? What you set DATABASES to in your settings.py file?

Comment: Are you run this command in the path that manage.py file is on there?

Comment: Yes I am running these commands from the same directory as manage.py. I did not get any output from any command. I am using postgreSQL.

Comment: Did you set  a virtual environment for your project? and if so, are you activating it before running migration commands?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. the problem was My postgresql settings had same `PORT=51697` which was causing problem. I replaced it to `PORT= ''` and it worked like a charm.

my settings is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'your database name',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
  }
}
```